# Struggling to reverse decryption algorithm in C

Tags: c, encryption, reverse

This is my first ever question on StackOverflow so if I do something wrong don't go too hard on me.
Anyways, I have found a certain encryption in a C file I was looking in and I have the decryption code but I have no clue on how to reverse it so I can encrypt my own string into it.

```
    int r;
    char str[] = {"4:;145;14;81583"};
    for(r = 0; (r < 100 && str[r] != '\0'); r++)
    str[r] = str[r] - 3;
```

The encrypted string (4:;145;14;81583) is the IP 178.128.185.250
Like I said, I am wondering how to reverse the decryption method so that I can encrypt my own strings. Help?

Comment: That solved it. That was so simple.

Comment: This was the part that confused me.

        for(r = 0; (r < 100 && str[r] != '\0'); r++)

Comment: It just means: Continue the loop until end of string (i.e. `str[r] != '\0'`) **or** at maximum 100 chars (i.e. `r < 100`) I have no idea why the max of 100 chars is added. Seems like pure nonsense

Answer (score 2):

It's straight forward: Decrypt is `- 3` so encrypt is `+ 3`

**Decrypt**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int r;
    char str[] = {"4:;145;14;81583"};
    for(r = 0; (r < 100 && str[r] != '\0'); r++)
        str[r] = str[r] - 3;
                //      ^ notice: minus
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
178.128.185.250
```

**Encrypt**

```
include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int r;
    char str[] = {"178.128.185.250"};
    for(r = 0; (r < 100 && str[r] != '\0'); r++)
        str[r] = str[r] + 3;
                //      ^ notice: plus
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4:;145;14;81583
```

**Edit:**

The line

```
for(r = 0; (r < 100 && str[r] != '\0'); r++)
```

is copied directly from OPs question. As far as I can see, it can be simplified to:

```
for(r = 0; str[r] != '\0'; r++)
```

without any problems.

Comment: I am puzzling over the `r < 100`. Could you explain?

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, I simply copied it directly from the question and didn't wanted to change it. But you're correct that it seems strange so I added some extra text to the answer.